# How to replace one characters with two possible characters in a string

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to know how to replace a string like `"10?01?1"` at `'?'` with `1` or `0`. E.g., from string `"1?0"` -> `"110"` && `"100"`. How to approach this problem? Recursive? Thanks.

**EDIT** with OP comment

> "1?0?1 ... it should have four different combinations. "11011", "11001", "10011","10001". How to print all four combinations?"

Comment: language?..............

Answer (score 1):

When you encounter a '?', replace it with a '0' and recur, then replace it with a '1' and recur.

```
private void permute(String s) { 
    ... 
    if (s.charAt(i) == '?') { 
        permute(<replacing '?' with '0'>);
        permute(<replacing '?' with '1'>); 
    } 
    ...
}
```

Comment: en, this looks like a good solution. Let me try on actual code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this code it gives for "1???" all combinations which are: 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111
as possible by 2^3= 8 combinations.

```
import java.util.*;

import java.lang.*;

import java.io.*;

 class testRecursion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        combinations("1???");
    }

    public static void combinations(String s) {
        if(s.contains("?")){
            combinations(replace(s, '0'));
            combinations(replace(s, '1'));
        } else {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static String replace(String s, char replacement){
        char[] charSeq = s.toCharArray();
        int i;
        for(i=0; charSeq[i]!='?'; i++);
        charSeq[i]=replacement;
        return new String(charSeq);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursively call next character and detect if the next character is a ? or not. If it is a ? replace it with 0 or 1.

Comment: This is what I thought too, I can't seem to finger out the code. how to replace it with 0 or 1?Can you tell in more specific detail?thanks

Comment: @nathan220 Your question seems to indicate that you actually want to do both. That is, when you encounter a '?' replace it with a '0' and continue recurring, and then replace it with a '1' and recur. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

*I want to know how to replace a string like "10?01?1" at '?' with 1 or 0*
you can replace it by using [replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or [replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

Example

```
String str= "1?0";
String replcaed=str.replace("?","1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach to get 4 combinations, but not all 8 combinations.
Because in this approach when recursion happens the string changes without'?' , but it will update the index in the memory. thats why its giving only four answers. If you increase the number it will give you different combination equals to the number
public class Recursion {

```
private static void replaceCharacters(char[] inputString, int stringLength, int characterIndex) {

    if (characterIndex < stringLength) {
        if (inputString[characterIndex] == '?') {
            inputString[characterIndex] = '1';
            replaceCharacters(inputString, stringLength, characterIndex + 1);
            inputString[characterIndex] = '0';
            replaceCharacters(inputString, stringLength, characterIndex + 1);
        } else {
            replaceCharacters(inputString, stringLength, characterIndex + 1);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(new String(inputString));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testString = "1???";
    replaceCharacters(testString.toCharArray(), testString.length(), 0);

}
```

}

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but it gives wrong answer. for "1???", it gives only four combinations which are: 1111, 1110, 1100, 1000. However, it should produce 2^3= 8 combinations. Is it correct?

Comment: @nathan220 This is because lines like `inputString[characterIndex] = '1'` don't just alter the `char[]` for the next iteration, it alters the argument that had been carefully crafted before the current iteration! The solution is to use a different `char[]` every time we recur. See the edit in the answer.

Comment: I see your point. It worked now. Instead of using array, we can get result pretty quickly if we use string since it won't alter its value when passed as  parameters.<code>public static void replace(String s, int n, int i)
 {
  if(i == n)
   System.out.println(String.valueOf(s));
  else
  {
   if(s.charAt(i) == '?')
   {
    s = s.substring(0,i) + "1" + s.substring(i+1,n);
    replace(s,n,i+1);
    s = s.substring(0,i) + "0" + s.substring(i+1,n);
    replace(s,n,i+1);
   }
   else
   {
    replace(s,n,i+1);
   }
  }
 }</code>

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    combinations("1?0?1");
}

public static void combinations(String s) {
    if(s.contains("?")){
        combinations(replace(s, '0'));
        combinations(replace(s, '1'));
    } else {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

public static String replace(String s, char replacement){
    char[] charSeq = s.toCharArray();
    int i;
    for(i=0; charSeq[i]!='?'; i++);
    charSeq[i]=replacement;
    return new String(charSeq);
}
```

OUTPUT

10001
10011
11001
11011

Comment: great answer,man. Can you provide an answer which doesn't not use java's internal functions replaceFirst(). Just use basic recursive. Thanks

Comment: And why you don't want to use internal function? if you can explain that I'll try to give you proper answer

Comment: Hi, I am wondering if there is basic method like reading character one by one recursively and print result. But yours is awesome too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int output = 0;
    int ip1_cols = 0;
    ip1_cols = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());

    in.useDelimiter(" ");
    char[] ip1 = new char[ip1_cols];
    for(int ip1_j=0; ip1_j<ip1_cols; ip1_j++) {
        ip1[ip1_j] = in.next().charAt(0);

    }
    enumerate(ip1);
    for (Iterator iterator = possibleAleternatives.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        String cs = (String) iterator.next();
        System.out.println(cs);
    }

}
static Set<String> possibleAleternatives=new HashSet();

static void enumerate(char[] charArr){

    for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++) {
        char c = charArr[i];

        if(c=='?'){
            findPossibleAlternatives(charArr, i);
        }
    }
    String s=String.valueOf(charArr);
    if(!s.contains("?")){
    possibleAleternatives.add(s);
    }
}

static void findPossibleAlternatives(char[] charArray,int i ){
    char[] newArr1=Arrays.copyOf(charArray, charArray.length);
    char[] newArr=Arrays.copyOf(newArr1, newArr1.length);
    newArr1[i]='0';
    enumerate(newArr1);
    newArr1=null;
    newArr[i]='1';
    enumerate(newArr);
    newArr=null;
}
```

A complete version without replaceFirst()