# Implementing combinations logic in java

Tags: java, logic

I need a program which has to find the possible combinations of a word after replacement. I tried my best to use *for loops* and temp variables but couldn't get it.

The user enters a string. The program has to replace all characters with their multiple mappings and show all the combinations.

Example:

**Input**: 100

Replace 1 with 2 or 3 or 4 or 5.

Replace 0 with A or B or C or D.

**Output:**

```
2AA
2AB
2AC
2AD
2BA
2BB
2BC
2BD
2CA
2CB
2CC
2CD
2DA
2DB
2DC
2DD
3AA
3AB
3AC
3AD
3BA
3BB
3BC
3BD
3CA
3CB
3CC
3CD
3DA
3DB
3DC
3DD
4AA
4AB
4AC
4AD
4BA
4BB
4BC
4BD
4CA
4CB
4CC
4CD
4DA
4DB
4DC
4DD
5AA
5AB
5AC
5AD
5BA
5BB
5BC
5BD
5CA
5CB
5CC
5CD
5DA
5DB
5DC
5DD
```

This is just an example given with 1 and 0. My program has from 1 to 9 and each of them has four mappings. The mappings are greek and latin characters.
Please help.

Comment: You could post what you've tried and we help you fix that. But giving a code from the scratch isn't what exactly you'd be expecting here.

Comment: I got a similar one in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151512/how-to-replace-one-characters-with-two-possible-characters-in-a-string). I got the answer. Thanks.